# template = operator not found

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I want to create template operator =, but it does not work;

```
class A
{
public:

    template<class T>
    A& A::operator=(const T& obj)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Yes, class is empty, but operator must work with any class.

```
void main()
{
    A a;
    a = 1.3;
}
```

But this gives error

Comment: `main()` should return `int`.

Comment: What is the error message that you receive? On my g++ (version 6.4.0), the only issue that I get with your code is: `error: extra qualification 'A::' on member 'operator=' [-fpermissive]
  A& A::operator=(const T& obj)`. Removing `A::` from the operator definition solved this issue. Also, as @O'Neil pointed, `main` should return a value.

Comment: @O'Neil @MxNx `main` always return an int, but a return statement in the body of main is not mandatory [\[basic.start.main\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.main#5): *If control flows off the end of the compound-statement of main, the effect is equivalent to a return with operand 0*.

Comment: @Oliv The return statement is indeed optional, but the return type is `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `A::` for member function definition inside class definition.

```
class A
{
public:

    template<class T>
    A& operator=(const T& obj)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NJJdQeYy3LhiK7cv)

Or you can define it out of the class definition.

```
class A
{
public:

    template<class T>
    A& operator=(const T& obj);
};

template<class T>
A& A::operator=(const T& obj)
{
    return *this;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G8jzmc09o0DJBVqV)

Comment: Wow. Thanks, I tried to define operator outside of the class, but this does not work.

Comment: @Demaunt I added both cases.